# Attach macro file to php excel generated file

Tags: php, excel, vba

My problem is the following... I am re-developing a system for a gym and I would like to make an excel file with macros in case Internet doesn't work. The problem arise when I want to generate my excel file (php) from my DB coz I don't know how to keep my macro functions attached to the file.

The idea behind is that, at the end of the day, the administrator generate that file so that, the next morning, if the internet is down, the gym can works with the latest info (with the macro and vb stuff).

I googled "php attach macro file to excel" but couldn't find a solution (I would have to previously develop the macro functionality).

Comment: You could put the data in a separate file from the macros: the macro file can just be a static download.  If you need more help then you'll need to add more detail to your question, such as how you're creating your Excel files in PHP

Comment: Thankx Tim !. I just figure out a way... I can have an excel file with macros and when generating the new one from the website, I can make a funcionality to import all the data instead of worrying how to attach the macros... I don't know If I made myself clear... I'll be arround...

Answer (score 0):

I use phpspreadsheet to make it works.

1. Write you vb macro code and debug in the excel VBA. (Develop tool > visual basic)
2. Save your excel in `.xlsm` format.
3. Unzip the `.xlsm` file, and you will find a `.bin` type file in the directory `xl`
4. Then use the macro with

```
$spreadsheet = new Spreadsheet();
$macroCode = file_get_contents(binfilepath.bin");
$spreadsheet->setMacrosCode($macroCode);
```

Note to use the macro, you also need to save it in .xlsm format.